# What does BIP mean?

Tags: bip, terminology

There is a lot of reference to BIP 16, 17 and the likes. What does BIP actually stand for? I'm unsure if this is a programming reference or a Bitcoin specific reference; either way I'm stumped.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

BIP = Bitcoin Improvement Proposal. The suggestion to use the concept of BIPs is [BIP 1](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/BIP_0001).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, BIPs are both a Bitcoin specific and a general programming reference as they were designed after the Python Enhancement Proposal ([PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0001/))

throughout any open source project you are likely to see PEPs and PIPs, HIPs, and even Ethereum Request for Comments (ERC) that all essentially play the same role of helping a distributed group of people work in an organized fashion.